# Avoid garbage collection when using sockets

Tags: android, performance, sockets, garbage-collection

In a game project of mine i'm trying my best to avoid the creation of objects and thus preventing the garbage collector from running.

It is a network game and I am mostly sending byte arrays of data but also some other objects like int arrays.

I have noticed when analyzing the memory allocation in eclipse that there are alot of byte arrays created in my program by the way I'm writing/reading to/from the sockets.

```
oos=new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(link.getOutputStream()));
ois=new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(link.getInputStream()));
```

How can I read / write (mostly byte arrays) from / to sockets without creating any more objects in the background?

Also what would be the fastest way to do this network communication? I need to squeez every bit of performance out of this application.

**EDIT**

I have changed my code a bit and i now only send loose bytes and ints through the oos.
Still there is allocations done.

[Allocations screenshot](http://data.fuskbugg.se/skalman02/4e393ac8c61f6_allocations.jpg)

Reading code

```
@Override
public void run() {
    super.run();
    byte packet = -1;
    while(connected){
        try {
            packet = ois.readByte();
            handlePacket(packet);
        } catch (OptionalDataException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            connected=false;
        }
    }

}

@Override
public void handlePacket(byte b) throws OptionalDataException, ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
    super.handlePacket(b);
    //TODO add more packets 
    switch(b){
    case Packet.SERVER_SEND_PLAYER_LOCATIONS:
        this.locations=(int[]) ois.readObject();
        break;
    case Packet.SERVER_SEND_PLAYER_COLORS:
        this.colors= (int[]) ois.readObject();
        break;
    case Packet.SERVER_SEND_WORM_WIDTH:
        wormWidth = ois.read();
        break;
    case Packet.SERVER_SEND_PLAYER_NUMBER:
        numberOfPlayers = ois.read();
        break;
    case Packet.CS_SEND_TURN:
        gp.addTurn(ois.read(),ois.read(),ois.readByte());
        break;
    }
}
```

Writing

```
    public void send(byte value){
    try {
        oos.write(value);
        oos.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
public void send(int value){
    try {
        oos.write(value);
        oos.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add a little more of your code, such as where oos and ois is being called. The answer really depends on the scope of those two variables. The smaller the scope the sooner they will be eliminated. If you would like to reuse the same object say within a loop, you can instantiate them one time, then reuse them inside a loop (as long as you are sure there are no side-effects of this)

Answer (score 0):

just make sure there's no references to those arrays !!!

some of your code will help